# React & Javascript optimization - arrays, spread, splice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization

I have a little problem understanding something. So I need your help to do an example for me. Please kindly write this two functions with a better solution.

the **setTempRecipe** is a coming from **useState** hook in my react functional component.

```
const addCustomizationOption = (co) => {
    const tmpR = Object.assign({}, tempRecipe);
    tmpR.customizationOptions.push(co);
    setTempRecipe(tmpR);
};
```

and the second one is:

```
const removeCustomizationOption = (co) => {
    const tmpR = Object.assign({}, tempRecipe);
    const g = tmpR.customizationOptions.findIndex(item => item.id === co.id);
    tmpR.customizationOptions.splice(g, 1);
    setTempRecipe(tmpR);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const addCustomizationOption = (co) => {
    setTempRecipe({
                   ...tempRecipe,
                   customizationOptions:[...tempRecipe.customizationOptions,co]
                  });
};


const removeCustomizationOption = (co) => {
    setTempRecipe({
                   ...tempRecipe,
                   customizationOptions:tempRecipe.customizationOptions.filter(i => i.id !== co.id)
                  });
};
```

Comment: take care that customizationOptions array must be instanciated before adding a customization option or it will crash. @AminNoura

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, you shouldn't mutate state variables, instead take a deep copy and apply new values. What I would go for is:

```
const addCustomizationOption = (co) => {
    setTempRecipe(tr => ({...tr, customizationOptions: [...tr.customizationOptions,co]}));
};
```

This spread operator will add `co` to the tempRecipe array and `tr` refers to the current state.

And, for the second one, you can filter the array:

```
const removeCustomizationOption = (co) => {
    setTempRecipe(tr => ({...tr, customizationOptions: tr.customizationOptions.filter(recipe => recipe.id !== co.id))})
};
```

Since `.filter()` function returns a new array, you can directly filter out the id and set the new filtered array.

Comment: It's wrong, tempRecipe is an object with props, not an array

Comment: needed to push into tmpR.customizationOptions

Comment: Yep, fixed it now. My mistake.